# PendingIntent funciona bien la primera vez pero despues sus acciones se repiten el doble de veces

Tags: java, android

Estoy haciendo una notificación personalizada para un reproductor, uso un metodo para crear la notificacion funciona bien la primera vez pero al enviarle datos a la notification por el MainActivity para cambiar el nombre de la cancion el boton funciona como si los pulsara dos veces mas, por ende si quiero pausar una cancion esta se pausa y se reanuda demasiado rapido.

**Metodo**

```
private void notification(String titulo){

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Intent previousIntent=new Intent(Constantes.ACTION.PREV_ACTION);
    ppreviusIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,previousIntent,0);

    Intent playIntent = new Intent(Constantes.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION);
    pplayIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, playIntent,0);

    Intent nextIntent = new Intent(Constantes.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION);
    pnextIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, nextIntent, 0);



    remoteViews=new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.notification);

    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.Titulo,titulo);
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.cover,R.drawable.music_player);
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.previus_notification,R.drawable.previus_notification);
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.play_notification,R.drawable.pause_notification);
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.next_notification,R.drawable.next_notification);
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.close_notification,R.drawable.close);

    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.previus_notification,ppreviusIntent);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.play_notification,pplayIntent);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.next_notification,pnextIntent);


    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("IMAPLAYER")
            .setTicker(titulo)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.music_folder)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContent(remoteViews).build();


    previus=new IntentFilter();
    play=new IntentFilter();
    next=new IntentFilter();

    previus.addAction(Constantes.ACTION.PREV_ACTION);
    play.addAction(Constantes.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION);
    next.addAction(Constantes.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION);

    receiver=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(intent.getAction().equals(Constantes.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION)){

                if(MyMediaSingleton.getInstance().player.isPlaying())
                {
                    MyMediaSingleton.getInstance().player.pause();
                    PAUSE++;
                }
                else
                {
                    MyMediaSingleton.getInstance().player.start();
                    PLAY++;

                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(ForegroundService.this, "PLAY:"+PLAY+" "+" PAUSE: "+PAUSE, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(receiver,play);

    startForeground(Constantes.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE,notification);
}
```

**Servicio**

```
public class ForegroundService extends Service {


private static final String LOG_TAG = "Service";
public static boolean IS_SERVICE_RUNNING = false;


private Notification notification;
private NotificationManager notificationManager;
private RemoteViews remoteViews;

private BroadcastReceiver receiver;
private IntentFilter previus;
private IntentFilter play;
private IntentFilter next;

private PendingIntent ppreviusIntent;
private PendingIntent pnextIntent;
private PendingIntent pplayIntent;

private int PLAY=0;
private int PAUSE=0;



@Override
public  void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags,int StarId){

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Constantes.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Received Start Foreground Intent ");
        String titulo=intent.getExtras().getString("key");
        notification(titulo);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


     return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

**Pase de datos**

```
public void SendToService(){
    Intent service=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ForegroundService.class);
    if(ForegroundService.IS_SERVICE_RUNNING){
        String path=recibidor_file.get(recibidor_position).getName();
        service.setAction(Constantes.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);
        ForegroundService.IS_SERVICE_RUNNING=true;
        service.putExtra("key",path);
        startService(service);
    }
}
```

De adelantado muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo pude resolver necesitaba que el SendToService mandara los datos a un especifico Action y alli adentro actualizarlos con starforeground, para evitar crear una nueva notification

**SentToService**

```
public void SendToService(){
    Intent service=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ForegroundService.class);
    if(ForegroundService.IS_SERVICE_RUNNING){
        String path=recibidor_file.get(recibidor_position).getName();
        service.setAction(Constantes.ACTION.DATA_ACTION);
        ForegroundService.IS_SERVICE_RUNNING=true;
        service.putExtra("key",path);
        startService(service);
    }
}
```

Usando ACTION.DATA_ACTION le decia al servidor que tomara una accion especifica

**Servidor**

```
  if(intent.getAction().equals(Constantes.ACTION.DATA_ACTION)){
        titulo=intent.getExtras().getString("key");
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.Titulo,titulo);
        startForeground(Constantes.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE,notification);
        Toast.makeText(this,"Sent data:"+titulo,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Con el intent.getExtras tomaba los datos enviados, el remoteview los enviaba a lo notificacion y el starforeground los actualizaba, asi no tenia la necesidad de volver a crear otra notificacion

Comment: Felipe, esto parece un comentario, agrega por favor parte del código para ser más especifico y que sea de ayuda a otros.